# Could I go vs Can I go

Tags: modal-verbs

My school teacher said that "Could I go?" is more polite than "Can I go?" but according to me "Could I go?" can not be used interchangeably but should be used as to infer that if I was allowed to go at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can I go to the bathroom, please?
- Could I go to the bathroom, please?

Your teacher is correct that the *could* version is (slightly) more polite.

You seem to be assuming that the only function of *could* is to express the simple past of *can*. But compare this function of *could*:

- If I could go anywhere, I would go to Bhutan.

This *could* is being used to describe a hypothetical situation (in a second conditional sentence), not something that happened in the past.

That is how you should understand the *could* of polite requests.

---

**Tip:** Don't overanalyse the how the grammar contributes to the meaning of polite language. It is often best simply to learn the polite phrases first. We might use:

- If you might just wait here for a minute...

rather than

- Wait here for a minute!

But looking for a *grammatical* reason to use the first option doesn't really help us. It's sometimes better just to learn the structures that can be used.

Comment: Thanks! As I am a non native speaker I try to relate it with my mother tongue(Hindi) so the logic that I applied holds true for Hindi. Thanks Once again mate!

Comment: No problem! What is the Hindi equivalent, out of interest?

Comment: Can go will be taken as the normal meaning of (like I can go there if i want to),but "could go" will be considered as "I could have gone there if I wanted (but now there is possibility of it). to add more politeness to "can go" in Hindi one would just say it more politely(polite diction) or with some complex words.

Comment: Cool. I was interested in the actual Hindi sentences though!

Comment: There you go! Hindi Translation for Can go's Example would be "मैं चाहूं तो वहां जा सकता हूं" for could go it will be "मैं चाहता तो वहाँ जा सकता था" Which basically means what I said in my previous comment.