# If 'Could i go?' is the kind way , What would be the past of 'Can i go'?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, questions

I was reading this [question & answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/268251/149312), he said that ‘Could I go?’ is the kind way. Then I've got the doubts that, how do I ask someone the past of the ‘Can I go?’?

Like

- Am I allowed go there yesterday?
- I could've gone there yesterday, could I?

Can I ask this like,  *Could I go there yesterday?*

Comment: It makes no sense to ask permission to do something yesterday! You can say "Could I have gone there yesterday?" (Would it have been allowed  if I had asked permission first?)

Comment: Take care with your writing of "I". In English the word "I" is always a capital, never "i".

Comment: Okay.. That's new information. I didn't know that  

To James K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal verbs, like "can" don't have complete tense systems.

The word "could" is sometimes used as a past tense of can:

> I could run a mile in 6 minutes when I was younger.

But "could" also has use as "present possibility" and in phrasing polite questions.

You *could* use "be able to" to talk about past or future abilities using tense:

> I was able to run a mile in 6 minutes when I was younger.

> I will be able to work as a teacher after I get my degree.

[The word *could* above is used to indicate present possibility. I've used it to show that "could" isn't always a past tense of can.]

Comment: So can I use ' Am i able to go there yesterday? ' ?
I hope it'll work

Comment: @deadday Please read James K's answer more carefully. The verb in "am I able" is "be", to express meaning in the past the auxiliary verb must be inflected, e.g. ***Was** I/he/she/it able* to go there yesterday? ***Were** you/we/they able…*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *could* has several functions, one of which is to be the past of *can*:

> *I can't find the restaurant, but I could last month*.

So *could I go there yesterday?* is possible, but rather unlikely, because you're unlikely to ask whether you were able to do something yesterday or not. But it can make sense to ask somebody else: *Could you go there yesterday?* (i.e. *Were you able to go there yesterday?*).

This is separate from *could* as a vaguer and more polite expression of possibility of permission. Sometimes a sentence using *could* can be formally ambiguous between the uses; but in most cases the meaning is clear from context.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate